# How to use self-signed and LetsEncrypt Certbot SSL certificates together in nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, ssl, server, digital-ocean

I am hosting a django website on digital ocean. I have wish to access my website's IP using https with self-signed cert as Let's Encrypt does not provide certificates for public IP addresses. I followed this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04) and wrote an nginx server block. I can access https://example-ip-address with:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name 123.123.12.123;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/djangotemplates;
    }

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name 123.123.12.123;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

And, I can access https://example.com and https://www.example.com with let's encrypt SSL cert by following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04) and this is the server block I wrote:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/djangotemplates;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

The problem here is when I put both server blocks into one single configuration file and access https://example-ip-address, the connection is then not encrypted. However, it works fine for https://example.com and https://www.example.com. Any idea what went wrong here?

I just started my django website live on digital ocean - and I received an error email 'Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '123.123.12.123'. You may need to add '123.123.12.123' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.' So, I added the ip address in the ALLOWED_HOSTS. And I think it's safer to visit the ip address with https.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use certbot instead of a self signed certificate
https://certbot.eff.org

Comment: this comment doesn't directly help the OP, alternate suggestions are welcomed but they must explain why the other approach is better